# How can I get user's continent without any HTTP calls?

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I have a list of servers in my game containing words "europe server", "usa server", etc. I want to sort them and show servers in the same user's continent higher. I don't want to add any additional permissions, nor make any HTTP calls(I feel like they will increase load duration). What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Locale.getDefault` or `TimeZone.getDefault` and set continent by the result.

Answer (score 0):

You consider using a local geolocation database. You just need to collect the user IP address and then query it from a database to get the country and continent information.

There are several free databases. For reference, you can download the free database from https://lite.ip2location.com/database-ip-country